# Posting a form to another website and show the web page in Iframe

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to post a form in codebehind and show the response in Iframe. Following code is opening another browser window with target url but now showing in Iframe.

This is my Aspx code:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" onclick="Button1_Click" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button2" onclick="Button2_Click1"  />
        </div>
    </form>

    <iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1"  frameborder="0" height="450px" width="100%" style="overflow:hidden;" scrolling="yes">
   </iframe> 
</body>
```

On Button1 click I try to post a form with following code. Everything works fine but new browser window open instead of opening it in Iframe.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<form id='ssoForm' name='ssoForm'  method=post action='" + formAction + "' target='iframe1'>");
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<input type='hidden' name='TARGET' value='" + formTarget + "' />");
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<input type='hidden' name='Encoding' value='B64' />");
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<input type='hidden' name='SAMLResponse' value='" + resp + "' />");
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");

    Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> document.forms['ssoForm'].submit();</SCRIPT>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the target attribute of the FORM tag to the name of your iFrame.  I believe this should work per the HTML spec, but I don't know if ASP.NET will honor it.

Alternatively, you could place the actual ASP.NET form in the iFrame, and have the parent page use JavaScript to set the values inside of the iFrame and submit the form within the iFrame.

Comment: Metthew - Thanks for your reply but before that I tried defining a form a aspx page itself.. setting hidden filed values on page load and on Button_click added OnClientClick to submit the form from javascript function.. Some how it worked.